# Magento Add To Cart button sends me to a blank screen

Tags: php, magento

When I click Add to Cart button on either the search results page, category page or inside the product page I get sent to a blank screen. I have turned on error displaying in php and also logging and nothing comes up in either.

I have tried disabling the compiler and refreshing the cache and nothing.

I feel like I have been searching all the forums and have tried anything.

I know it's tough without either a trace or an error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a blank page then it seems to be a PHP error. The steps to debug it would be:
1. Make sure error reporting is turned on, write temporarily:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

at the beginning of of index.php file.
2. change theme to a different one. I'd suspect error in
app/design/[package]/[theme]/template/checkout/cart.phtml
3. disable local and community modules.